# Can you specifically assign / bind a virtual network adapter to the server's physical network interface on VMware Workstation?

Tags: networking, virtual-machines

Hi I'm trying to install Centos and Snort on a virtual machine and is there anyway I can bind the promiscuous virtual network adapter to a specific physical network interface on the server? I'm using VMWare workstation 7.1.4.

If I recall correctly VM Virtual Box can do that if you set the Virtual Network Adapter to Bridged. However I can't seem to find that option in VMware Workstation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: workstation and server doesn't belong in the same question on this site

Answer (score 0):

You can run [Virtual Network Editor](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1018697) to build a special virtual interface that you can bridge your VM to.